# upload file/directory with ftp

Tags: java, ftp

I have setup openssh server in ububntu machine.
I want to upload file and dierctory to ftp server using java api's.
So, far i have used two different vendors java api's(jscape, zehon) to upload  file/directory.

I am able to upload file/directory from local machine to local ftp server.
But i am not able to upload from local machine to remote ftp server using api's.
But with command line tools like scp or ftp or sftp i am able to upload file/directory from any local machine to remote ftp server.

I am confused whether i have not installed/configured openssh server properly.
or may be i am not able to use (zehon/jscape)java api's correctly.

can u please give me a test code to upoad file and directory using java api.

this is the code which i have used to upload file from local machine to remote ftp server.
I am using sftp.jar from jscape.

```
Ftp ftp = new Ftp(hostname,username,password);
ftp.connect();
ftp.setDir(destFolder);
ftp.upload(new File("local file path...");
ftp.disconnect();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sftp or scp is **NOT** ftp. And openssh can provide only sftp or scp. It can't provide openssh. Try vsftpd instead.

Answer (score 3):

We've been using [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) library, and I can recommend it. Example of usage: (I've dropped try-catch block and check whether FtpClient is connected)

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
..
private FTPClient ftpClient; //needs to be initialized
..
ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
ftpClient.setDataTimeout(timeout);
ftpClient.setDefaultTimeout(timeout);
ftpClient.connect(hostname, port);
ftpClient.setSoTimeout(timeout);
ftpClient.login(username, password);
ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); // or FtpClient.ASCII_FILE_TYPE, up to you
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(destFolder);
srcFile = new File("local file path.."); // replace with actual path
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
ftpClient.storeFile(filename, fis);
```

Comment: Hi Mijen,   i tried your solution but still i am facing same problem as i am able to upload a file from local machine to local ftp server but not able to upload file from local machine to remote ftp server.

Comment: Then the problem isn't in the library used, but somewhere else. Can you connect to the FTP server through shell (i.e., using ordinary ftp command)? What error do you face when trying to run my program?

Comment: Hi Mijen, this code runs in server machine where this webapp is deployed and openssh server is installed but what code to run in client machine so, that he can upload file from his local machine to remote ftp server.

Comment: Hi, please try to answer my questions in previous comment, without more information it's hard to locate the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

By using commons-net-3.0.jar provided by Apache you can communicate with Server with FTP.

FTPUtils Class is having core methods like connect,disconnect,upload and download methods.
and FTPMain having main method to upload file.

FTPUtils:

```
package com.ftpclient.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class FTPUtils {
    public static void ftpConnect(FTPClient ftpclient, String host, String username, String password) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("FTPUtils :: Logging in FTP..");
        try{
            ftpclient.connect(host);
            if (!ftpclient.login(username, password)) {
                throw new IOException("Supplied wrong credentials to FTP Server");
            }

            if (ftpclient.getReplyCode() != 0) {
                System.out.println(ftpclient.getReplyString());
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("FTP Client is not able to Connect to host");
            throw new IOException("FTP Client is not able to Connect to host");
        }
        System.out.println("FTPUtils :: FTP Login Successful..");
    }

    /**
     * disconnect to FTP server
     * 
     * @param ftpclient is Object which is having details of FTP server like IP, user name and password
     * @throws IOException throws Exception
     */
    public static void ftpDisConnect(FTPClient ftpclient) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("FTPUtils :: FTP Logging out..");
        ftpclient.logout();
        ftpclient.disconnect();
        System.out.println("FTPUtils :: FTP Disconnected Successfully..");
    }

    /**
     * download's file from source path to destination path by using FTP Client.
     * 
     * @param ftpclient is Object which is having details of FTP server like IP, user name and password
     * @param sourcePath is String from where to download's file
     * @param destinationPath is String to where to download's file.
     * @return boolean true if download's with out any fail else false
     * @throws IOException will throw any problem with file system
     */
    public static boolean downloadFile(FTPClient ftpclient, String sourcePath, String destinationPath) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("FTPUtils :: RemoteFile download starts ..FTP SOURCE " + sourcePath + " DESTINATION " + destinationPath);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        boolean result = false;
        try{            
            ftpclient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpclient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            File fDestination = new File(destinationPath);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fDestination);
            result = ftpclient.retrieveFile(sourcePath, fos);
            if (result) {
                System.out.println("FTPUtils :: RemoteFile download Completed..FTP " + sourcePath);
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("FTP is not able to Download the files from host");
            throw new IOException("FTP is not able to Download the files from host");
        }finally{
            fos.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @param ftpclient
     * @param sourcePath
     * @param destinationPath
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void uploadFile(FTPClient ftpclient, String sourcePath, String destinationPath) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            //
            // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
            //
            fis = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);

            //
            // Store file to server
            //
            ftpclient.storeFile(destinationPath, fis);
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("FTP is not able to upload the files from host");
            throw new IOException("FTP is not able to upload the files from host");
        }finally{
            fis.close();
        }
    }
}
```

FTPMain:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class FTPMain {
    public static void main(String[] str){
        FTPClient ftpclient = new FTPClient();
        try {
            FTPUtils.ftpConnect(ftpclient, "ipaddress", "username", "password");
            FTPUtils.uploadFile(ftpclient, "sourcePath", "destinationPath");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```